# Optimal way to analyze user qualifications data (C# and SQL server)

Tags: c#, sql-server, algorithm, data-analysis

I need to analyze data from SQL server table. Table contains data connected with  qualifications of all employyes in the company and has the following structure (simplified):

```
| User    | Qualification | DateOfQualificationAssignment |

| user000 | Junior        | 2014-01-15                    |

| user000 | Middle        | 2014-02-15                    |

| user001 | Middle        | 2014-02-02                    |

| user001 | Senior        | 2014-03-18                    |

| user002 | Senior        | 2014-02-19                    |

| user003 | Junior        | 2014-03-04                    |
```

I need the way to determine number of employees having given qualification for the concrete date. It should be some sort of analyze("Qualification", "Date") function returning the folowing for these types of input data:

- analyze("Junior", '2014-01-20') - returns 1 (it is user user000)
- analyze("Junior", '2014-02-20') - returns 0 (because user000 became Middle on 2014-02-15)
- analyze("Middle", '2014-02-25') - returns 2 (because user000 and user001 are having Middle qualification on 2014-02-25)
- analyze("Middle", '2014-03-28') - returns 1 (user000 is still Middle, but user001 became Senior on 2014-03-18)

Currently I have no idea how to handle this efficiently. What approach can be used to achieve my goal?

Comment: I would query in SQL directly. `WHERE Date > ... AND Date < ...` should work without problems

Comment: Did you mix up the dates in case 4 or do I miss something here? In any case this sounds like a problem that should be solved using reporting rather than coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think this should satisfy your requirements:

```
create function dbo.analyze(@qualification varchar(50), @date date)
returns int
as
begin
   declare @result int;
   with cte
   as
   (
       select t.*, rank() over (partition by t.[User]  order by t.DateOfQualificationAssignment desc) r
       from theTable t -- no clue what the real table is named
       where t.DateOfQualificationAssignment < @date       
   )
   select @result = count(*) 
   from cte
   where cte.r = 1 and cte.Qualification = @qualification
   return @result;
end
go
```

Tested with your data:

```
create table theTable
(
    [User] varchar(50) not null,
    Qualification varchar(50) not null,
    DateOfQualificationAssignment date not null
)
go

insert into theTable([User],Qualification,DateOfQualificationAssignment)
values
('user000','Junior','20140115'),
('user000','Middle','20140215'),
('user001','Middle','20140202'),
('user001','Senior','20140318'),
('user002','Senior','20140219'),
('user003','Junior','20140304')
go
```

and the results:

```
select dbo.analyze('Junior','20140120') --returns 1
go

select dbo.analyze('Junior','20140220') --returns 0
go

select dbo.analyze('Middle','20140225') --returns 2
go

select dbo.analyze('Middle','20140328') --returns 1
go
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `row_number() over()` in a derived table to enumerate the rows on `DateOfQualificationAssignment descending` partitioned by `User` where `DateOfQualificationAssignment` is less than the date you want to check on.

In the main query you count the rows with the enumerated value `1` and `Qualification`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e205c/1)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```sql
create table T
(
  [User] char(7),
  Qualification char(6),
  DateOfQualificationAssignment date
)

insert into T values
('user000', 'Junior', '2014-01-15'),
('user000', 'Middle', '2014-02-15'),
('user001', 'Middle', '2014-02-02'),
('user001', 'Senior', '2014-03-18'),
('user002', 'Senior', '2014-02-19'),
('user003', 'Junior', '2014-03-04')
```

**Query 1**:

```sql
declare @Qualification char(6) = 'Middle'
declare @Date date = '2014-03-28'

select count(*)
from (
     select T.Qualification,
            row_number() over(partition by T.[User] order by T.DateOfQualificationAssignment desc) as rn
     from T
     where T.DateOfQualificationAssignment < @Date
     ) as T
where T.rn = 1 and
      T.Qualification = @Qualification
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e205c/1/0)**:

```
| COLUMN_0 |
|----------|
|        1 |
```